# Textblock over the elipse slider thumb - avoid resize of grid behind elipse when text is changing C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I would like to implement textblock with actual value of slider on the top of elipse slider thumb. When textblock have the same widht as elipse everything is working properly but I need to increase the width of textblock.

After width of textloblock changes also width of grid for elipse changed and slider is not looking proper anymore.

1. Picture of slider with textblock width = elipse width
    [textblock width = elipse width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIoVt.png)
2. Textblock width higher than elipse width
   [texblock width higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OHSO.png)

Do you have any idea how to avoid situation from picture 2?

Slider thumb style:

```
            <Thumb x:Name="SliderThumb">
               <Thumb.Style>
                 <Style  TargetType="Thumb">
                   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                   <Setter Property="Template">
                     <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Thumb">
                         <Grid  Background="Transparent">
                           <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="Blue" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                           <TextBlock  Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,80"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" 
                            Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                         </Grid>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
            </Thumb.Style>
          </Thumb>
```

**EDIT:
Full code according to issue with text centering.**

MainWindow:

```
 <Grid>
    <ContentControl   Height="70" Width="400">
       <Slider x:Name="slider2"  IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Tag="mm" Maximum="210"  Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource Horizontal_Slider}"/>
    </ContentControl> 
</Grid>
```

Slider style:

```html
            <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Border Height="10" Background="Red"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Border Height="10" Background="Blue" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>
           
           
           <Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Grid MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=ellipseThumb, Path=ActualWidth}"                                                      Background="Transparent">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseThumb" Fill="Blue" Height="30"Width="30"/> 
                                 <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,100" ClipToBounds="False"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=valueTextBlock, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=valueTextBlock, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                    <TextBlock                   
                                       Background="Transparent"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                       FontSize="24"> 
                                       <Run Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat={}{0:F2}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                                       <Run Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            
            
            
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomSlider"  TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track"   >
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="DecreaseSlider" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="SliderThumb"  Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"  />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="IncreaseSlider" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>              
            </ControlTemplate>



           <Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomSlider}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your `TextBlock` in a `Canvas` to avoid clipping, and also you need to not set the width for `TextBLock` to let it get the size it need.

Here is a working code for your case:

```xml
<Thumb x:Name="SliderThumb">
    <Thumb.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=ellipse, Path=ActualWidth}">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="Blue" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                            <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,80"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=valueTextBlock, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=valueTextBlock, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="valueTextBlock"
                                           Background="Transparent"
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           FontSize="24"
                                           Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Thumb.Style>
</Thumb>
```

**Update**

Here is a better style for `Thumb` with better alignment

```xml
<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=ellipseThumb, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=ellipseThumb, Path=ActualHeight}"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseThumb" Fill="Blue" Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Canvas Grid.Row="0"
                            Height="{Binding ElementName=valueBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=valueBorder, Path=ActualWidth}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Border x:Name="valueBorder">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                       Background="Transparent"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="24">
                                <Run Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat={}{0:F2}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have wrapped the `TextBlock` inside a `Border` to allow it to have margin.

**Note:** I set `Foreground` color of `TextBlock` to Black for testing purpose.

Comment: thank you very much! it is working excellent. I have one more question if you could help: How to center text than, right now when it is long text like "100 mm" it is starting right above ellipse and wrraping to right. I would like to center it. I tried to set Margin for canvas like this (0,0,80,80) and change HoritzontalAlignment of Canvas to left but seems that it is maximum to left.

Comment: Well, I tested my code with very long text and it was centered as it should, so what I suggest is to ensure that the width of `Canvas` is binded to the actual width of `valueTextBlock`.

Comment: I've binded width of Canvas. How long is your text? For short text like percentage value (50 %) it is also fine but it is moving to right for longer text like (101.22 mm). Have you also tried longer text?

Comment: It works fine, I just tried your value and here is the [result](https://imgur.com/ANJ9dos). If you want, edit your question and add your actual code to be able to have a look.

Comment: Ok, I've put full code in edited question. Thank you for tour help again.

Comment: As I expected, the issue was in binding the width of `Canvas`. You removed the name `valueTextBlock` from the `TextBlock` which display the formatted value thus the `Canvas` was not able to find the binding source for its `Width` and `Height`.  However, once you fix it you will have some alignment issue of the whole `Slider`, I will update my answer with improved style for `Thumb`.

Comment: Omg I am so low. Thank you for your patience and help!